# How to set border color in High Contrast mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

The website I'm working on has an accessibility toggle. When high contrast mode is on it adds various outlines and/or borders to buttons, links and input elements. Currently their color (of the borders and outlines) is set to `#000`, but it won't matter - they always appear black.

I'm testing this in Firefox on a Mac, by checking off the `Preferences -> Content -> Colors -> Allow pages to choose their own colors, instead of my selections above` checkbox.

It looks good when the Background option is set to white. But once it's set to black, I see no borders, because they are black as well.

So - how do I detect light/dark high contrast themes (`-ms-high-contrast` is no good for me) and/or how do I set a white border when background is black?

Comment: Your accessibility toggle will likely switch the website's CSS style sheet -- you'll need to find that style sheet to edit the accessibility styles.

Comment: Yes, the styles are switched. What I'm asking is HOW exactly to edit the accessibility styles in that new stylesheet so that I catch both cases I've described?

Comment: when you say the "background option is set to black" -- is this a thing the user can select as part of the accessibility toggle?

Comment: Here's what I mean - https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/2B0p430O011T1q2p0A12/Content.png

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a browser specific setting (which allows users to override the website's stylesheets). You won't be able to detect or override these settings (that's the point of them -- give the user control over appearances). That checkbox in your snapshot which says "Allow pages to choose their own colors, instead of my selections above" -- if it is unchecked, then you're no longer in control. Its not under your jurisdiction, so to speak.

Answer (score -1):

Set `border: 1px solid transparent;`